# How to check if python cv2.imwrite worked properly

Tags: python, file, opencv, image-processing

I would like to check if `cv2.imwrite` executed properly and my file was saved. I tried to use exception handling with `try-except`, but if, for example, there is no folder named `foo/` in any case it would be printed: `"Image written"`

```
try:
    cv2.imwrite("foo/img.jpg", myImage)
    print("Image written")
except:
    print("Problem")
```

P.S. Checking after saving is not an option, because the file could be overwritten.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Python cv2.imwrite() has a return value, True if the write succeeded, False if it failed.

So do something like

```
writeStatus = cv2.imwrite("foo/img.jpg", myImage)
if writeStatus is True:
    print("image written")
else:
    print("problem") # or raise exception, handle problem, etc.
```

Comment: Oh, so simple! Thanks!

Comment: No problem. As far as I know it is not documented on the OpenCV pages.

Comment: Yes, there is nothing about return value in it.

Answer (score 2):

```
if cv2.imwrite(<path>, image_data):
     print('Image write succeeded')
else:
     print('Image write failed')
```

> Single line (For fancy coders):

```
print('Image write:',"Succedded" if cv2.imwrite(<path>, image_data) else "Failed")
```

> Both of them works as of Python v3.7

Comment: Welcome to SO! Thank you for your time in answering this question. Your solution is just a minor variation of the accepted answer. Also, the question was asked and answered one year ago. Be sure to look at the date of the original question when answering.

Comment: Well, thanks for mentioning but given the way the coding style has been changing, I think its important to provide a new way as well along with the old solution.